# Counter-Example for Riesz representation Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

The following is an exercise of Conway's Functional analysis, chapter 1, section 3.

Let $H=L^2(0,1)$ and $C^{(1)}$ be the set of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$ that have a continuous derivative. Let $t\in [0,1]$ and define $L:C^{(1)}\longrightarrow \mathbb{F}$ by $L(h)=h'(t)$. Show that there is no bounded linear functional on $H$ that agrees with $L$ on $C^{(1)}$.

Comment: it wouldn't quite make sense, as $L$ is not a functional, it is an operator.

Comment: I'm voting to un-put-on-hold [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777348/separable-hilbert-space-l2-mu).

Comment: @RudytheReindeer the link you mention does not work anymore. One is supposed to use Reisz Representation theorem for Hilbert spaces for this answer. Can you help answer it?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $h_n(t)=\sin nt$. What is the $L^2$ norm of $h_n$? And of $h_n'$?

Comment: How does one prove it using Reisz representation theorem?

Comment: @user531706 The counterexample does not rely on the Riesz representation theorem at all. The title of the question is misleading in that regard: Perhaps it happened because the exercise was in or near a section on the Riesz representation theorem in the textbook.